# why doesn't my REST call work on subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, post

I have successfully used a REST call to create a list item in my root site and now need to use a second one to populate a list item in a sub site with the same data.

Here are my dictionary settings

Site Creation Call:

**header**

content-type - string - application/json;odata=verbose

accept       - string - application/json;odata=verbose

**metadata**

type         - string - SP.Data.[variable: TargetList]ListItem

**JSONRequest**

__metadata   - dictionary - [variable: metadata]

site creation parameters:

**parameters**

parameters   - dictionary - [variable: JSONRequest]

**HTTP Call Settings**

```
[variable: TargetURL]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('[variable TargetList]')/items
```

Call Type: POST

This renders a link in the format:

```
http://server/rootsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
```

this works fine for the root site but fails with a bad request error when I add the sub site in like this:

```
http://server/rootsite/web/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
```

Is there a different format I should be using for the connections to sub sites or is it that I'm trying to undertake 2 REST calls with the same workflow?

Comment: Check if you are getting the metadata property correct or not?

Comment: You can verify it is correct or not using `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listName')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName`.

Comment: how are you passing the subsite url

Comment: @SunilSahu I have a variable called TargetSiteURL which holds the root URL: http://server/sites/mysite. That is all I use in the first workflow (the functioning one) in the second workflow I add a second variable (SiteTitle) to give the following URL structure for the subsite http://server/sites/mysite/<variable:subsite title>/

Comment: @Ganesh I'm still learning about the REST api. could you write something comprehensive about how to use the ListItemEntityTypeFullName to verify the metadata property?

Comment: You need to pass `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` while creating new list item in `__metadata` property. You can log the value of `[variable: metadata]` to history list also in browser window, hit the URL I have given in above comment and check if it is same as the [variable: metadata].

Comment: @Ganesh Thankyou for the clarification, Yes the values are identical. I'm still getting the BadRequest response when I run the REST call

Comment: Welcome. Also check if you are passing wrong data type value to column with different data type... Like number/date time/lookup/person or group.

Comment: Have tried using hardcoding the subsite url instead of using variable?

Comment: @Sunil, subsite has to be variable as this workflow will be used in a template. the subsite url has to change with each use.

Comment: yes, I know just wanted you to check whether the url formation is correct or not. So with hardcoding the url

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, SharePoint gives you more details on your error in the response Body.

Does SharePoint returns HTTP 400 only ? 
Can you give us more details ?

Comment: All SharePoint tells me is BadRequest. When I run the call in Fiddler I get a 403 permissions error but I am the SCA and in the Owners group and the subsite inherits permissions for the root. There are no app steps or elevated permissions present so everything should be running against my user account permissions which are Full Control.

Comment: you should open your rest call error result and expand the returned "data" parameter and search for the different errors.